# Get correct file modification time in a git repository (in ruby)

Tags: ruby, git

In a git repository in which I switch back and forth between branches, file modification times as shown by `mtime` in ruby (or the operating-system based measure of the modification time, e.g. through `ls -l`) show the time I last changed branches instead of the actual time the file was modified.

I understand Git stores file modification time for all files, but how do I get the actual modification date displayed, e.g. from a ruby call?

e.g. I see I can get this from the command line:

`git log -1 --format="%ad" -- path/to/file`

but not sure what the best Ruby way to do this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not possible; i.e. that git stores only the commit time, not the modification time. However, you might want to check out [metastore](http://david.hardeman.nu/software.php), which is an addition to git that stores this metadata in a separate file.

However, since the commit time is sufficient for your purposes, you can run the command directly from ruby; something like:

```
%x(git log -1 --format='%ci' path/to/file)
```

Or you can use one of the [ruby git libraries](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/git_Tools). I have never used these libraries myself, so I can't really vouch for any of them.

EDIT: Added the part about commit time, since that was sufficient for OP's purposes.

Comment: Not sure why the commit time would not be the last modification time of the file.  So accessing the last time the file was committed would be fine for my case.  Not sure why I need metastore.

Comment: The commit time is for the commit itself, it has nothing to do with anything about the committed tree.

Comment: @cboettig Ah, if the commit time is sufficient, you can retreive it by looking at the first log entry for the file. Oh ... and now I see you've edited your post with the git log example. To access this from ruby, you might run the command directly; something like `%x(git log -1 --format='%ci' path/to/file)`, or use one of the [ruby git libraries](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/git_Tools). I have never used these libraries myself, so I can't really vouch for any of them.

Comment: @Steinar commit time works for me (guess as long as commits are made on the same day as edits this is reasonable).  I wrote a plugin based on your answer https://github.com/cboettig/labnotebook/blob/4bf8b20420da1efb1c9a94ec7bb12c7c768b68da/_plugins/jekyll-labnotebook-plugins/git_modified.rb.  If you'd like to edit your answer I will accept it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: @cboettig I'm glad this worked out for you. I've updated the answer as requested. Also, it's cool that you've shared your plugin for achieving this, I'll be sure to check it out!